# PDO misbehaving with bind parameters

Tags: php, pdo

I have simple SQL query that could benefit from bind variables so I have written like this:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM activities WHERE user_id=':user_id' AND date(start_time)=date(':on_specific_day')");
$stmt->bindParam(':user_id',$where['user_id']); 
$stmt->bindParam(':on_specific_day',$where['on_specific_day']);
```

As you can see there is an associative array called `where` which is used to store my where conditions. When I execute this statement it doesn't return any errors but the row count is zero. If I instead discard my dream of using bind variables and do this:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM activities WHERE user_id='{$where['user_id']}' AND date(start_time)=date('{$where['on_specific_day']}')");
```

The query runs just fine and returns 2 results in my test case. Can someone help me from slipping into madness. :^)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to enclose your `PDO parameters` with quote marks:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM activities WHERE user_id=:user_id AND date(start_time)=date(:on_specific_day)
```

Comment: To explain a bit: parameters in prepared queries are complete variables, not just text to be substituted. So a string variable doesn't need extra quotes, because the DB already knows it is a string.

Comment: I love a simple answer. Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot!