# echo data from database PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Trying to echo out in this case the users username. I've had a friend help me, but he seems like he can't solve it either. So I'm asking you guys.

Basically, I'm right now trying to take the username from the person who logged in. The sessions which get set when you log in is called "user_id". Never mind, this is my code`

```
            $user = $dbh->prepare("SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = ':user_id'");
            $user->bindParam(':user_id', $_SESSION['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $user->execute();

            while($row = $user->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)){
            $user_name = $row['1'];

            }
            ?>
                <h3>Welcome <p class="blue"><?php echo $user_name;?></p></h3><br/>`
```

With this, I get this error:
Undefined variable: user_name in

i know this is wrong, since it obviously doesn't work. But I've also tried setting sessions at that place in the while loop like this.

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['username'];
```

but then I get a blank result. Which means that there's no value of the session, or am I wrong?

Comment: Why don't you store the username in the session on login?

Comment: Duplicate of recent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16875257/pdo-misbehaving-with-bind-parameters

Comment: You're using apostrophes around your placeholder  :username in your prepare statement. Try removing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need quotes in the `$row` variable

```
while($row = $user->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)){
   $user_name = $row[0]; 
}
```

In your original code, its `$row['1']`. You don't have a field called `1` so remove the single quotes from around it.

Also, rows (when numerically indexed) start at 0, so the username field would be `$row[0]`

**EDIT**

And to touch on what @jeroen mentioned, in your SQL query, you shouldn't have quotes around your parameterized values:

```
$user = $dbh->prepare("SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = :user_id");
```

Comment: Also don't need the quotes around the variable in the prepared statement.

Comment: Yeah, my friend actually added the quotes in the query :P But they are gone now. I have ID has 0, so username is 1.

Comment: And its still not working? Have you tried the change in my edit, as mentioned by @jeroen?

Comment: No, it's still not working :( It still gives me Undefined variable: user_name

Comment: When you say that ID is actually 0, you aren't `selecting` ID in your query. So it would still be `$row[0]` unless you have `SELECT ID, username, ...`

Comment: Alright, I've changed. Still no result :( Still says that "$user_name = $row[0];"   is a undefined variable.

Comment: If your sure `$user_name = $row[0];` and you've also removed the quotes in the SQL around `:user_id`, AND your sure that the user ID exists in the database, I can't see anything else thats wrong unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

When there is no data returned, `while` won't be executed even once.
So, check your query.

Answer (score -1):

To start you never checked if the user actually exists in the database, so what I personally would do is prepare the query and set a value to the default username- run the query and if no rows are returned then do nothing, if we actually have a row then fetch the corresponding column value in that row ('username') and set the variable to that.

```
$user = $dbh->prepare("SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = ':user_id'");
$user->bindParam(':user_id', $_SESSION['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$user->execute();

$UserName = "Unknown!";

while( $row = $user->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM) ){
    $UserName = $row['username'];
}

echo '<h3>Welcome <p class="blue">{$UserName}</p></h3><br/>';
```

Comment: I just wanna echo the username, I've already made the loginsystem, so it checks and all that stuff. To mention, it didn't work :P